# App Crashes when configured for release but not for debug

Tags: ios, xcode, build, testflight

I'm sure the issue is that the stack size is too small. I fixed the issue in debug configuration by adding these flags, -Wl,-stack_size,200000, to other linker flags on the Build Settings page. but it doesn't seem to be working when configured for production. What do I need to change? Thanks.

### Crash Report

```
Incident Identifier: 88175B24-3669-4D7F-9966-952268597045
CrashReporter Key:   1946f6179f09e3738b175275139089c9cd614b77
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             LC-Project [4987]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/58D676EF-2E1F-4CD9-8115-D80E6AE652BD/LC-Project.app/LC-Project
Identifier:          org.prhuffman.lc-sudoku
Version:             9 (1.0.9)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.prhuffman.lc-sudoku [2371]


Date/Time:           2017-06-11 13:19:39.8359 -0500
Launch Time:         2017-06-11 13:19:39.7042 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000016fb40930
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   LC-Project                      0x00000001000ff7dc 0x1000f0000 + 63452
1   LC-Project                      0x00000001000fb974 0x1000f0000 + 47476
2   LC-Project                      0x00000001000fb974 0x1000f0000 + 47476
3   LC-Project                      0x00000001001015ac 0x1000f0000 + 71084
4   UIKit                           0x0000000190f7fec0 0x190f70000 + 65216
5   UIKit                           0x0000000190f7fa9c 0x190f70000 + 64156
6   UIKit                           0x0000000190f8631c 0x190f70000 + 90908
7   UIKit                           0x0000000190f837b8 0x190f70000 + 79800
8   UIKit                           0x0000000190ff5224 0x190f70000 + 545316
9   UIKit                           0x00000001911fd7ec 0x190f70000 + 2676716
10  UIKit                           0x00000001912031e0 0x190f70000 + 2699744
11  UIKit                           0x0000000191217d18 0x190f70000 + 2784536
12  UIKit                           0x0000000191200474 0x190f70000 + 2688116
13  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018c9f7884 0x18c9bd000 + 239748
14  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018c9f76f0 0x18c9bd000 + 239344
15  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018c9f7aa0 0x18c9bd000 + 240288
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018adfd42c 0x18ad22000 + 898092
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018adfcd9c 0x18ad22000 + 896412
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018adfa9a8 0x18ad22000 + 887208
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ad2ada4 0x18ad22000 + 36260
20  UIKit                           0x0000000190fea384 0x190f70000 + 500612
21  UIKit                           0x0000000190fe5058 0x190f70000 + 479320
22  LC-Project                      0x0000000100103724 0x1000f0000 + 79652
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000189d3959c 0x189d35000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f0eca8 0x189f0e000 + 3240

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f0eca8 0x189f0e000 + 3240

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f0eca8 0x189f0e000 + 3240

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e49a88 0x189e2a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f0f1a4 0x189f0e000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f0ecac 0x189f0e000 + 3244

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f0eca8 0x189f0e000 + 3240

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e2b224 0x189e2a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189e2b09c 0x189e2a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018adfce90 0x18ad22000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018adfaae4 0x18ad22000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ad2ada4 0x18ad22000 + 36260
5   Foundation                      0x000000018b844d74 0x18b838000 + 52596
6   Foundation                      0x000000018b865b44 0x18b838000 + 187204
7   UIKit                           0x000000019196f6a8 0x190f70000 + 10483368
8   Foundation                      0x000000018b9422d8 0x18b838000 + 1090264
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f1168c 0x189f0e000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f1159c 0x189f0e000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000189f0ecb4 0x189f0e000 + 3252

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000014dd0cf70   x1: 0x00000001001040b6   x2: 0x000000014de0f680   x3: 0x000000016fd0d968
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000000000018   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x74593e6c3ad900b8   x9: 0x000000016fb40930  x10: 0x00000001b0fa9ff0  x11: 0x00519b0100519b80
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000519b00  x14: 0x0000000000519c00  x15: 0x0000000000519bc0
   x16: 0x0000000000519b01  x17: 0x00000001000ff7a8  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000014dd0cf70
   x20: 0x0000000191ac72bc  x21: 0x0000000170055ab0  x22: 0x000000010010c000  x23: 0xb000000000000d02
   x24: 0xb000000000000cb2  x25: 0xb000000000000cc2  x26: 0xb000000000000cd2  x27: 0xb000000000000ce2
   x28: 0xb000000000000cf2   fp: 0x000000016fd0deb0   lr: 0x00000001000fb974
    sp: 0x000000016fb40880   pc: 0x00000001000ff7dc cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x1000f0000 - 0x100107fff LC-Project arm64  <eff2c8363e8c3ace99664e609ab2f79e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/58D676EF-2E1F-4CD9-8115-D80E6AE652BD/LC-Project.app/LC-Project
0x100124000 - 0x10012bfff libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib arm64  <6c06c91109a736b0ac616be1c592fd81> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
0x1001cc000 - 0x1001fffff dyld arm64  <a3339f99c2ea39d8beb70b8ff2e84061> /usr/lib/dyld
0x189830000 - 0x189831fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <2e9654eb84903bd7aee0815fd9d27591> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x189832000 - 0x189887fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <da0f6a86db853140b2d79e3b36f28795> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x189888000 - 0x1898a4fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <5dc5ba28cfa43f838099049d17ba9ec6> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1898a8000 - 0x189c85fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <85f3b59b96243690b138ce96e663bf4b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x189c86000 - 0x189c8afff libcache.dylib arm64  <5d1024035c983afdacc90dad2f0280ec> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x189c8b000 - 0x189c96fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <0ca00f1d89553b9e8ad032310e8ecbb8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x189c97000 - 0x189c9afff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <771427d857db3158b2f7d971afa219c9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x189c9b000 - 0x189ca2fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <793e7046ae7c3b65b17d6e0d9fe975fd> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x189ca3000 - 0x189d04fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <66d47f7529873633892967a26e598456> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x189d05000 - 0x189d34fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <1643bcf57daf389784dfcad8c485fd3e> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x189d35000 - 0x189d39fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <6c6a61f720cf30daa4a357cbefbf4cd6> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x189d3a000 - 0x189d3afff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <1539b0564b4b34f78ab27c96400c3619> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x189d3b000 - 0x189d40fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <9434199c06b73b7090f38d0d0f6e6c20> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x189d41000 - 0x189d42fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <2262f08800e630af981ed21f7240d32e> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x189d43000 - 0x189d5afff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <8c876d02afeb3aa18e733bbdbfa074f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x189d5b000 - 0x189d5bfff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <45adbecbe4b93744911aa6314fbbc8ff> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x189d5c000 - 0x189dd8fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <31008bfe57f7313a974fad1f76e24496> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x189dd9000 - 0x189dddfff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <99e65007dcd2368da0a7896f491ece18> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x189dde000 - 0x189de3fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <62636c63790b3c0d9cc115fc73d66ba2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x189de4000 - 0x189de5fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <9eec7dc8a2d831639eaf9bd9b3e70377> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x189de6000 - 0x189dfefff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <f7a5e11e082d37babe31812e9717fcf0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x189dff000 - 0x189e05fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <9700821f537737e4b2f91607acb78aa7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x189e06000 - 0x189e29fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <077e4a85b19f3b00b768a5eb34fe46b5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x189e2a000 - 0x189e4efff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <275624061b1a3ab391baf08b4ba58a97> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x189e4f000 - 0x189e7bfff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <d8e9248df4523f35a7ac365dab827fba> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x189e7c000 - 0x189e97fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <56104290e798374188ef0da981dc3146> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x189e98000 - 0x189ef1fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <54ba9caf24023fd0ad569557ac08b1a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x189ef2000 - 0x189efbfff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <8aef40a6317b3062b40dc94d87f7d1bf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x189efc000 - 0x189f06fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <1da4fe88c1ad31b6a5c7c2138f5d1c94> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x189f07000 - 0x189f0dfff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <a0a582b8f653379e8ac7799e83c90b1f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x189f0e000 - 0x189f17fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <8f14c41e6536348a9b6ffd2a82be7d57> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x189f18000 - 0x189f1bfff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <ac550550955c37c2b2e4022095b4b8de> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x189f1c000 - 0x189f23fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <39c51c9bffa030ef82de6c281436e836> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x189f24000 - 0x189f36fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <3fdd15d2b2c33d68b8cc600d0482b5fd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x189f37000 - 0x189f3cfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <990bab05c7b333f3bfc274d5ea579b71> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x189f3d000 - 0x189f3dfff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <dabe83c40ec235dfb7f0e8fe395e1844> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x189f3e000 - 0x189f64fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <7a12d1ee49b73e1eb582b9c359c7fe79> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x189f65000 - 0x18a17afff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <d7b181cad9a438e7b6e010c2e4c8da5e> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x18a17b000 - 0x18a18cfff libz.1.dylib arm64  <ab0d683d7cf931e49e5456a420ced72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x18ad22000 - 0x18b0a3fff CoreFoundation arm64  <719044f95fe23ee0ab14504def42b100> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x18b0a4000 - 0x18b0b4fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <4f2930cfb67e3965a863f8bfb7704300> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x18b0b5000 - 0x18b0b5fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <5cfceffa0be736398124efbb3d80cbd1> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x18b0b6000 - 0x18b131fff IOKit arm64  <6f72fc6ac9d2309dbf33c8b014c129d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x18b132000 - 0x18b152fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <5674397d74c33492a16f51f6fd33f114> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x18b153000 - 0x18b23cfff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <605bee9eb5ff3c43a65d251460f3650c> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x18b23d000 - 0x18b2d7fff Security arm64  <287bf21cb54734b9b91574ccb4e71436> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x18b2d8000 - 0x18b343fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <57d2eead9fcf34ecaa81c225ad8345e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x18b344000 - 0x18b454fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <aa3a5cd643b43e40b5680d5a3758ab8f> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x18b455000 - 0x18b7c9fff CFNetwork arm64  <05331a42dd8b31cea6ef547eadc487cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x18b7ca000 - 0x18b7d7fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <29e1c06129583bb5b423bbfd7397c0e5> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x18b7d8000 - 0x18b7f0fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <eb9e235443573c948bcd016ea00a3709> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x18b7f1000 - 0x18b80bfff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <a859d30f7de034a2bee5aa662bc5bc2d> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x18b80c000 - 0x18b835fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <a31887c5b46a3b97ad308f4db869be43> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x18b836000 - 0x18b837fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <80d66702d7ce30b7b75c3f75472697eb> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x18b838000 - 0x18bb07fff Foundation arm64  <08e6a29fdbac38dd817c66cedf0e0052> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x18bb08000 - 0x18bbb3fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <708d8599265c39d3881fc57c55bc982d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x18bbb4000 - 0x18bee2fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <96e5ce2234903263ad30c6398972d535> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x18bee3000 - 0x18c17dfff vImage arm64  <1f67094759de381898830a3692edff0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x18c17e000 - 0x18c1a3fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <3de044e80d883d6188e8ce8a8572ec5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x18c1a4000 - 0x18c1b8fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <37c71c692da03cc9a1534badab1cf6f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x18c1b9000 - 0x18c1cafff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <2237c532ebe539f8ab93c181dfa1a291> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x18c1cb000 - 0x18c240fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <0ced33b1008e357e9acb9d039cff697d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x18c241000 - 0x18c241fff vecLib arm64  <d21c98b0003235f99d247f4f934c7641> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x18c242000 - 0x18c242fff Accelerate arm64  <f38de9acd0ba3a00a1c32fda7a240f38> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x18c243000 - 0x18c787fff CoreGraphics arm64  <7d39f265eae8328f801705549c70e571> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x18c788000 - 0x18c79cfff GraphicsServices arm64  <b5749f3fa6f13ce689683db33f23256c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x18c79d000 - 0x18c7eafff AppSupport arm64  <2a60ffa70fa13031a1251b964802ad31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x18c7eb000 - 0x18c918fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <78cfd6fb54fa3b2abaa4006791ac96ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18c919000 - 0x18c97afff BaseBoard arm64  <ff0febbec86337aead2c18f8ac460dec> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18c97b000 - 0x18c98afff AssertionServices arm64  <8ff92082f5833b7795af4a2200886ce2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18c98b000 - 0x18c9b8fff BackBoardServices arm64  <7bd5622615bb39cdba684e47e9bb8798> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18c9bd000 - 0x18ca0cfff FrontBoardServices arm64  <6adf5e0649313e35bd11d448eb071d17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x18ca10000 - 0x18ca44fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <a5f42cadcaba3943953f5047533c2fe7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x18ca45000 - 0x18ca5ffff MobileKeyBag arm64  <51a5be975d3a37c2af8751a5b9124948> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x18ca60000 - 0x18ca68fff IOSurface arm64  <acecdca025ff36b4b14159e52e2819dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x18ca69000 - 0x18ca74fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <3904292ecd513a0e85216e7c3abd1101> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x18ca75000 - 0x18ca8bfff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <b06bf5fa4c9b36f595a2a8ea4a84cca9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18ca8c000 - 0x18ca8efff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <7dd37fd295f93ecfa89401bbbb418dbf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x18ca8f000 - 0x18cacffff AppleJPEG arm64  <d8b98c13f8d83200ad41d6b30d3c9c14> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x18cad0000 - 0x18d05dfff ImageIO arm64  <9133dcebff4c3ab6807f96f884190cb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x18d05e000 - 0x18d064fff TCC arm64  <b11f764c841d3c69a50a6b0993735d43> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x18d065000 - 0x18d069fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <fab7b20283e43d8aa268b7d051e3d521> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18d06a000 - 0x18d076fff PowerLog arm64  <a668cd2a3ad03c0291a9665f3151f946> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x18d077000 - 0x18d0e1fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <a9cba41bffa83838b49c3f8ff2538f8a> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x18d0f5000 - 0x18d10afff libcompression.dylib arm64  <c5e41b4a6cbf37fb87cd5cd44f6906b8> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x18d10b000 - 0x18d3a3fff CoreData arm64  <7574c4fafa7a33bf82e05d9fa01ed542> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x18d3a4000 - 0x18d3a9fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <07e215340c3239fea6c469df55183bcd> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x18d3aa000 - 0x18d3affff IOAccelerator arm64  <54e24860953b39ddbe13a2dcdf76c733> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x18d3b0000 - 0x18d3b1fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <02280e05346d31509d62ac2583f72857> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x18d3b2000 - 0x18d3b5fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <f5c0306167ea39b2b60185329c1a8bbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x18d3b6000 - 0x18d3f7fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <34bb7e96428f3c1abd6f0cbb2787b9e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x18d3f8000 - 0x18d402fff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <d70b4c465ebe3a9e98c2b82ccf8fb7d7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x18d403000 - 0x18d40bfff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <e759626dff9439309f66279b3e4296ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x18d40c000 - 0x18d40cfff libmetal_timestamp.dylib arm64  <b51cc6027bd833d4a2a80f0d1de8bc40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
0x18d40d000 - 0x18d46efff Metal arm64  <0dc267ebbc333fcfa409b09544725b5f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x18d46f000 - 0x18d479fff OpenGLES arm64  <d789825652ac31c78f1007fed0ff3777> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x18d47a000 - 0x18d49efff CoreVideo arm64  <ba0cdc15666b32f7be6f9fcd1528c7f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x18d4e6000 - 0x18d5d8fff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <1db28a41c3a83551aad361a4e072fe33> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x18d5d9000 - 0x18d726fff CoreAudio arm64  <34f7497d8b43383cb4021a8300855c94> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x18d727000 - 0x18d72afff UserFS arm64  <b8862d7a16d83d22954ab81b89743009> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x18d72b000 - 0x18d838fff CoreMedia arm64  <8d8137d106813d32a14ce6e1f8384c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x18d8ca000 - 0x18d9d7fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <a7990cbb692b36a49280088c24b9ec2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x18d9d8000 - 0x18da67fff VideoToolbox arm64  <59e3d13a5d243b44abf10a5c4ba313f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x18da68000 - 0x18da68fff FontServices arm64  <5a9fc52851583aac96b6745cf7aae370> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x18da69000 - 0x18dbb5fff CoreText arm64  <851f6498f833335fb35ec9e67515c2fb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x18dbb6000 - 0x18dbd0fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <a3544981c8743eea875d5b7c7bc5b19b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x18dc01000 - 0x18e055fff AudioToolbox arm64  <0505b7dd6a033bf78117a8cd81a1101b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x18e056000 - 0x18e233fff QuartzCore arm64  <416a878f23c636fc8d81404ff7dd4fdc> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x18e23b000 - 0x18e24bfff libcmph.dylib arm64  <903e25509e37307e99af188ed1272633> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x18e26d000 - 0x18e35efff LanguageModeling arm64  <c49bcbbac36d34308151388e8bf1a718> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x18e456000 - 0x18e46cfff libmarisa.dylib arm64  <96c399295cb13cad829c93b5c29f0661> /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib
0x18e46d000 - 0x18e53dfff ProofReader arm64  <bb56e538be8835199a0abd263adb75f8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x18e53e000 - 0x18e548fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <17fe4943f5363a278cf9868db2623b9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x18e549000 - 0x18e559fff MobileAsset arm64  <2a3a006162af37b79c3a6b2ab71344c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x18e55a000 - 0x18e5cbfff ColorSync arm64  <996fd30495c33a64b17b87797c54aec2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x18e5cc000 - 0x18e63cfff MetalPerformanceShaders arm64  <e78463e7ed8334909ae0968c5b4ddcbc> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x18e63d000 - 0x18ea6cfff FaceCore arm64  <0179b0a45e4932e5967336ac40c0c4d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x18eaea000 - 0x18ecb3fff CoreImage arm64  <8c5c510a2d90361696f6a965b6b933a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x18ecb4000 - 0x18ed03fff TextInput arm64  <a1a56e91cb0534e8815a23fb6993b023> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x18ed04000 - 0x18ed14fff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <fbd694050c503c12a3e0e7dfb490b9df> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x18ed24000 - 0x18f766fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <f4afe098cd9b33c2b3369773851e26b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x18f9b9000 - 0x190baefff WebCore arm64  <d0a2b6b3b79434a08272968e20cd00a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x190baf000 - 0x190bd7fff libxslt.1.dylib arm64  <3edbcb1d6e1d33519db363daf35cfe1c> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x190bd8000 - 0x190d44fff WebKitLegacy arm64  <a7feeddf725930858e5fe93e4e047bb5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x190d45000 - 0x190e0afff CoreUI arm64  <0a25c84cf6183efead20a5cea30b98ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x190e0b000 - 0x190e32fff DictionaryServices arm64  <dd7a3952ff63333ebe91d7eff8347628> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x190e33000 - 0x190e36fff HangTracer arm64  <13e35bff690836b7b717f3f5ff690897> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HangTracer.framework/HangTracer
0x190e37000 - 0x190e8bfff PhysicsKit arm64  <e53aecfb95ec3252986a82a83a3cafd1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x190e8c000 - 0x190f63fff UIFoundation arm64  <db0623abf2243a578bd1e457f6877483> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x190f70000 - 0x191d17fff UIKit arm64  <4ad90348edcc3d21983f83490705f2aa> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x193148000 - 0x19314dfff ConstantClasses arm64  <d1824269bde13011a30bb20413b487c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x1963e9000 - 0x196456fff libprotobuf.dylib arm64  <9c108882e95c3003a9140280a9da8250> /usr/lib/libprotobuf.dylib
0x196877000 - 0x1968a8fff DataDetectorsCore arm64  <a6010e00f70239889cbdaaaf2325df0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x1968b7000 - 0x196b17fff libAWDSupportFramework.dylib arm64  <2c1184b25c6130d29445782aa1fe9b73> /usr/lib/libAWDSupportFramework.dylib
0x196b5a000 - 0x196b9afff WirelessDiagnostics arm64  <8aab71ecbfba39c78621cdf43f93a4d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
0x197a4e000 - 0x197ac7fff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <a1d866db069538fc90aaae3ca1ccb13d> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x19b9df000 - 0x19ba3dfff CoreBrightness arm64  <3cbc7c04794738d3a761dde2fd830fd1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreBrightness.framework/CoreBrightness
0x19fa2d000 - 0x19fa41fff libCGInterfaces.dylib arm64  <8d96c27fbf1235749dd2907472688e89> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Libraries/libCGInterfaces.dylib
0x1a08f2000 - 0x1a0900fff AppleFSCompression arm64  <9ce16a16e20c35f5be292f251083c30d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleFSCompression.framework/AppleFSCompression
0x1a1601000 - 0x1a1626fff CoreServicesInternal arm64  <3c2db4f07ea232358a78e76307363ba0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x1a1d9a000 - 0x1a1da6fff libGSFontCache.dylib arm64  <ad96a7db4ef337a1919ef9e4f24ce96a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x1a4806000 - 0x1a49d5fff libFosl_dynamic.dylib arm64  <8e1668637c423351a9b8f75d3db4e1bd> /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
0x1a4df1000 - 0x1a4e23fff libpcap.A.dylib arm64  <5b50b83d66ba3127ab8bfb9d7773aeab> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x1a5210000 - 0x1a5233fff UserNotifications arm64  <dea565113b183df0a2d4cd6a375f3142> /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications
0x1a5706000 - 0x1a57a9fff TextureIO arm64  <a427c8b881e43dad8d3c812bc418d731> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextureIO.framework/TextureIO
0x1a6c7d000 - 0x1a6c8ffff libBNNS.dylib arm64  <7b15b1fd47de37cc94234f1279febec2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBNNS.dylib
0x1a6c90000 - 0x1a6c94fff libQuadrature.dylib arm64  <6142532815973d5f9292892fb7c2c353> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libQuadrature.dylib
0x1a70ee000 - 0x1a70fffff CoreEmoji arm64  <02de2177a2a83b389b2d8796f9576d41> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/CoreEmoji
0x1a7776000 - 0x1a7842fff NLP arm64  <9162fa12a5ab3325a413c57dad3dce48> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NLP.framework/NLP
0x1a8abb000 - 0x1a8b33fff libate.dylib arm64  <8f60d460abd031edaf8477a229c4006c> /usr/lib/libate.dylib
0x1a8b34000 - 0x1a8b34fff libcoretls.dylib arm64  <852a1f8d67063962b6699bd608ee1eef> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
0x1a8b35000 - 0x1a8b36fff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64  <85a72486fa0e376f8b14a6d19375a1b6> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib

EOF
```

Comment: App on Testflight is build with Release config. Did u try running code in xcode with Release config?

Comment: Might be a good idea to connect the Xcode console to your phone when you start the app. This might show an error log. The error log could be added to your question.

Comment: @iAviator the app crashes in Xcode with release configuration.

Comment: I'd recommend you first learn how to symbolicate a crash log... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports